Error when installing rpy2 with pip, cannot find libffi.a
I am working on Rocky Linux and I want to work with R through python.
I have already installed R successfully.
Now I want to install rpy2, and pip install rpy2 fails with error:
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/rpy2/rinterface_lib
  /external/gcc-11.2.0/bin/gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I~/devel/jupyter_projects/.venv/include -I/external/python/python-3.10.13/include/python3.10 -c rpy2/rinterface_lib/_bufferprotocol.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/rpy2/rinterface_lib/_bufferprotocol.o
  /external/gcc-11.2.0/bin/gcc -shared -L/local/build/libffi/_install/lib64 -l:libffi.a build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/rpy2/rinterface_lib/_bufferprotocol.o -L/external/python/python-3.10.13/lib -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/rpy2/rinterface_lib/_bufferprotocol.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:libffi.a
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

libffi is installed but I don't have the static lib, only the dynamic one.
Then I triy to comple rpy2 locally, and the message is the same but maybe more precise:
  building '_rinterface_cffi_api' extension
  /external/gcc-11.2.0/bin/gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DRPY2_RLEN_LONG=True -DR_INTERFACE_PTRS=True -Irpy2/rinterface_lib/ -I/local/.venv/include -I/external/python/python-3.10.13/include/python3.10 -c _rinterface_cffi_api.c -o ./_rinterface_cffi_api.o -std=c99
  /external/gcc-11.2.0/bin/gcc -shared -L/local/build/libffi/_install/lib64 -l:libffi.a ./_rinterface_cffi_api.o -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -L/external/python/python-3.10.13/lib -lR -ltre -lpcre2-8 -ldeflate -llzma -lbz2 -lz -ltirpc -lrt -ldl -lm -licuuc -licui18n -lflexiblas -o ./_rinterface_cffi_api.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so -Wl,--export-dynamic -fopenmp -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib64/R/lib64
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:libffi.a
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  rpy2/_rinterface_cffi_build.py:301: UserWarning: LinkError: command '/external/gcc-11.2.0/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1

I understand that the problem is due to the presence of the parameters -L/local/build/libffi/_install/lib64 -l:libffi.a. I don't have a /local/build/libffi, which seems to me as a path generated for another configuration than mine, and also that it should not be link with static libffi but rather with libffi.so
But I would prefer to use pip install, the normal way of installing such a package, and I cannot see how to make it.
Thanks for your help
